# How do we get waiting queue size, throughput, time in the queue for play framework 2.1.0 in java?

Tags: java, httpclient, akka, playframework-2.1

Play framework maintains a queue to serve client side requests. Is there a way that we can get how many requests are in queue, what's the delayed time for each request before it is served by play server and what's the throughput?